# Separated logs in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Long time ago it was possible to set different log files for each class or class hierarchy in Rails, just doing for instance

class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
self.logger=Logger.new('log/ActiveJob.log')

and the same in each descendent class

Now, running with rails 6 **and Spring**, I find that the last defined log overwrites the previous ones. Is there any other recipe?

I also notice that there is some systematic in the overwriting. For instance, perhaps all the descendent of ActiveJob get a wrong log file, but the descendents of ActiveRecord get a different logger.

Any clue about what should happen if I do `self.logger=Logger.new('nameOfClass.log')` for each model, controller and job?

EDIT: I have tried `self.logger=` in the class definition and `MyClass.logger=` after the definition of the class. Neither work.

Answer (score 1):

> Any clue about what should happen if I do
> self.logger=Logger.new('nameOfClass.log') for each model, controller
> and job?

Don't know about model, but i'm declaring logger = Logger.('class_name.log') in each controller and job as result can check controller_a.log or controller_b.log / job_a.log or job_b.log separately

UPDATE:

For example (controller)

```
# a_controller
def AController < ApplicationController
  before_action :clogger
  def index
    @logger.info("index")
    ...
  end

  def show
    @logger.info("show")
    ...
  end

  private
    
    def clogger
      @logger = Logger.new('path_to_log/a_controller.log')
    end
end

# b_controller
def BController < ApplicationController
  before_action :clogger
  def index
    @logger.info("index")
    ...
  end

  def show
    @logger.info("show")
    ...
  end

  private
    
    def clogger
      @logger = Logger.new('path_to_log/b_controller.log')
    end
end
```

And i got a and b controllers log separately. it works same with jobs.

Comment: have you checked this recently? I was using self.logger instead of directly logger, is it not the same? If it is, then for 6.0 it doesn't work anymore. I get activations of job_a logged in job_b.log

Comment: Yes、but in api_only mode. 
logger = Logger.new('log/fun_slack.log') for a helper
logger = Logger.new('log/a_controller.log') for a controller
logger = Logger.new('log/b_controller.log') for another controller
etc.

But i have not tried self.logger.

Comment: @arivero
Updated it. I hope it will help.

Comment: Ah fun. Instance variable instead class variable. I had not considered it.

Comment: i guess it was not useless. GL.

Comment: I do not know what is better. Class variable you open the log once, instance variable keeps opening and closing the log. In both cases multiple processes could be writing there.